# How to access kerberized cluster using snakebite python client

Tags: python, snakebite

I have been struggling with how to pass requisite parameters to snakebite utility for it to be able to access a kerberized cluster. I have tried setting the necessary conf dir in the /usr/local/etc/hadoop path, as well as initialising and getting a ticket using kinit.

Any help or working example in this regards would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I have tested that the environment setup is proper by using 'hadoop' CLI to access the cluster from the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use autoconfigure class for this purpose:

```
from snakebite.client import AutoConfigClient
client = AutoConfigClient()
```

It supports HA and is auto configured through the HADOOP_HOME environment variable.

Please make sure that you also have a valid keytab

The klist output for the environment looks as follows (there is only 1 entry in there)

```
Credentials cache: API:1350E541-0CCD-46B9-938E-2C1C8E03A909
    Principal: saurabh@HADOOP_DEV.MY-COMPANY.COM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
May 31 16:45:30 2017  Jun  1 02:45:30 2017  krbtgt/HADOOP_DEV.MY-COMPANY.COM@HADOOP_DEV.MY-COMPANY.COM
```

This allows me to successfully list directories on the HDFS

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/saurabh
```

Comment: tried using this too. but didn't work. How to specify the location of keytab file for the client? I have already done kinit on the edgenode though.

Comment: Can you post output from klist?

Answer (score 1):

You must kinit with proper keytab is enough.  It will take automatically by the principal name to fetch results.